# Issues installing sklearn_pandas package

Tags: python

I have been trying to install the sklearn_pandas package. I tried two methods which I found online:

1) By running 'pip install sklearn-pandas' in the Windows command line in the same location as my Python working directory:
This resulted in the error ''pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' So I tried 'python -m pip install sklearn-pandas'. This got executed but showed nothing (no message/warning etc) in terms of output.
After this I attempted to import a function from sklearn_pandas in a code (using Spyder IDE), but got an error saying 'No module named 'sklearn_pandas''.

2) After the above, I attempted another suggestion which was to execute 'easy_install sklearn_pandas'. I ran this in the Spyder IDE and got an error saying invalid syntax.

Could someone help me out with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your pip doesn't recognized and constantly showing this message while executing: `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` If your python version is 3.x.x format then you use pip3 not pip anymore. The usage is pip3 is exactly the same as pip

Comment: I tried step 1 above, this time using pip3 instead of pip. I ran 'python -m pip3 install sklearn-pandas' in Windows command line in same directory as my Python working directory. Same result as before - no message/warning etc in Windows command line, and the module not found error in Spyder. Tried restarting Spyder and repeating the import, but still no success. Probably indicates that the library is either not installed or installed in another location. How do I find this out?